How to select mesh elements using an expression?
I'm using QGIS (3.34.7) and I'm trying to get a grip on meshes.
In this example, I'd like to select mesh elements within a polygon layer (and later export them).
QGIS (3.22) introduced "Select mesh elements by existing geometries" but it doesn't quite work as I want it to.
In my test-setup, I've got a mesh layer "Testmesh" and a polygon shapefile layer "Boundary". I would like to select all mesh-elements inside the polygon layer.

When using the tool "Select mesh elements by existing geometries", all elements that touch the polygon shapefile layer get selected:

My goal is to only select the elements that are completely inside my polygon shapefile layer.
I'll have to use an expression ("Select mesh elements by expression") to define my selection. Unfortunately, I have no idea how to go about it as I can't find any examples for expressions with meshes. My guess is that "overlay_contains" or "overlay_within" should do the job but I have no idea how to call them using mesh geometry.
